# Filter in react query not working properly on first attempt

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I am trying to get only females from an array using a filter, but on the first attempt react query returns the whole array, after that it is working fine. Any idea what property I have to add or remove, so this side effect disappears.
Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import getPersonsInfo from "../api/personCalls";

export default function Persons() {
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([]);
  const { data: personData, status } = useQuery("personsData", getPersonsInfo, {
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      setPersons(data.data);
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });

  const getFemaleOnlyHandler = () => {
    const result = personData.data.filter(
      (person) => person.gender === "female"
    );
    setPersons(result);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={getFemaleOnlyHandler}>Female only</button>
      {status === "loading" ? (
        <div>Loading ... </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          {persons.map((person) => (
            <div>
              <p>{person.name}</p>
              <p>{person.lastName}</p>
              <p>{person.address}</p>
              <p>{person.gender}</p>
              <p>{person.country}</p>
              <p>{person.city}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

I added the full code in code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-drake-4juxg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are making the mistake of copying data from react-query into local state. The idea is that react-query *is* the state manager, so the data returned by react-query is really all you need.

What you are experiencing in the codesandbox is probably just `refetchOnWindowFocus`. So you focus the window and click the button, react-query will do a background update and overwrite your local state. This is a direct result of the "copy" I just mentioned.

What you want to do is really just store the user selection, and calculate everything else on the fly, something like this:

```
const [femalesOnly, setFemalesOnly] = React.useState(false)
const { data: personData, status } = useQuery("personsData", getPersonsInfo, {
    onError: (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

const getFemaleOnlyHandler = () => {
    setFemalesOnly(true)
};

const persons = femalesOnly ? personData.data.filter(person => person.gender === "female") : personData.data
```

you can then display whatever you have in `persons`, which will always be up-to-date, even if a background update yields more persons. If the computation (the filtering) is expensive, you can also use `useMemo` to memoize it (compute it only when `personData` or `femalesOnly` changes - but this is likely a premature optimization.

Comment: I see, so I just added refetchOnWindowFocus: false and it is working fine. But I am not sure if that is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: no, it's not. you shouldn't copy the data to local state. There might be other ways where react-query will make a background update, in which case your data will be overridden again :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally familiar with `react-query` however the problem is likely that it is re-fetching (async!) everytime the component updates. Since `setPersons()` triggers an update (ie. sets state) it'll update the new `persons` state to be the filtered female list and then trigger a fetch of all persons again which comes back and sets the `persons` state back to the full list (ie. see what happens when you click the female filter button and then just leave it).

There is a more idiomatic way to achieve this in React which is to keep a *"single source of truth"* (ie. all the persons) and dynamically filter that based on some local ui state.

For example see below where `data` becomes the source of truth, and `persons` is a computed value out of that source of truth. This has the benefit that if your original `data` changes you don't have to manually (read: imperatively) update it to also be females only. This is the *"unidirectional data flow"* and *"reactivity"* people always talk about and, honestly, it's what makes React, React.

```js
  const { data = { data: [] }, status } = useQuery(
    "personsData",
    getPersonsInfo,
    {
      onSuccess: (data) => {},
      onError: (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  );
  const [doFilterFemale, setFilterFemale] = useState(false);

  const persons = doFilterFemale
    ? data.data.filter((person) => person.gender === "female")
    : data.data;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-nobel-9n117?file=/src/Persons/persons.jsx

This is ofc assuming you are always just loading from a json file. In a real application setting, given a backend you control, I would always recommend implementing filtering, sorting and pagination on the server side otherwise you are forced to over-fetch on the client.